# Defining Primtive Recursion for multiplication in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I am new to Isabelle and I am trying to define primitive recursive functions. I have tried out addition but I am having trouble with multiplication.

```
datatype nati = Zero | Suc nati

primrec add :: "nati ⇒ nati ⇒ nati" where
"add Zero n = n" |
"add (Suc m) n = Suc(add m n)"

primrec mult :: "nati ⇒ nati ⇒ nati" where
"mult Suc(Zero) n = n" |
"mult (Suc m) n = add((mult m n) m)"
```

I get the following error for the above code

> Type unification failed: Clash of types "_ ⇒ _" and "nati"
>
> Type error in application: operator not of function type
>
> Operator:  mult m n :: nati
>
> Operand:   m :: nati

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `mult` function: It should look like this:

```
primrec mult :: "nati ⇒ nati ⇒ nati" where
  "mult Zero n = Zero" |
  "mult (Suc m) n = add (mult m n) m"
```

Function application in functional programming/Lambda calculus is the operation that binds strongest and it associates to the left: something like `f x y` means ‘`f` applied to `x`, and the result applied to `y`’ – or, equivalently due to Currying: the function `f` applied to the parameters `x` and `y`.

Therefore, something like `mult Suc(Zero) n` would be read as `mult Suc Zero n`, i.e. the function `mult` would have to be a function taking three parameters, namely `Suc`, `Zero`, and `n`. That gives you a type error. Similarly, `add ((mult m n) m)` does not work, since that is identical to `add (mult m n m)`, which would mean that `add` is a function taking one parameter and `mult` is one taking three.

Lastly, if you fix all that, you will get another error saying you have a non-primitive pattern on the left-hand side of your `mult` function. You cannot pattern-match on something like `Suc Zero` since it is not a primitive pattern. You can do that if you use `fun` instead of `primrec`, but it is not what you want to do here: You want to instead handle the cases `Zero` and `Suc` (see my solution). In your definition, `mult Zero n` would even be undefined.